# Problems installing Open Gapps on Huawei Honor 7x

Tags: installation, google-apps

I tried to install [Open Gapps](https://opengapps.org/) to a Huawei Honor 7x mobile with twrp. I had strange problems during the installation:

1. It detected a wrong architecture with version 7.1 pico package: the phone is ARM64 but it complained it was ARM.
2. Using version 8, it says the ROM version is 7.1.x which in fact, it is Android 8.0.
3. The /system partition has about 500MB free space, but it cannot install pico because it says there is no enough space.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you try to install Gapps over a stock system with Google Apps already installed?!?! That will cause nothing but issues, "gapps" are only intended for custom ROMs or the few Chinese models that do not include any Google services.

Comment: I tried to install Gapps to a Chinese phone with stock ROM which has no Gapps. I am not sure it's a problem of TWRP  or Gapps. My feeling is the error messages are misleading.

Comment: You will probably need a custom ROM... Huawei devices use a heavily modified version of Android, and in Chinese models it is becoming a thing where the device is setup to block Google Apps by design.

Comment: That's probably correct in terms of getting Gapps on to the device. Still, my questions of the misleading error messages still not answered.